# Mix Design: Failure to predict response

Tags: experiment-design, qq-plot, quadratic-form, adjustment

I have performed a mixture design containing 3 terms and I have carried out 6 experiments needed to adjust a quadratic model. It fitted the data quite well:

```
> Call: lm(formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2 + x1:x3 + x2:x3, data
> = input)
> 
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -3.8050 -0.7975 -0.1750  0.3625  8.3850 
> 
> Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)    5.645      1.354   4.168 0.000522 *** x1            11.830      1.748   6.766 1.83e-06 *** x2            25.688      1.915  13.411 3.88e-11 *** x3                NA         NA      NA       NA     x1:x2        -22.025      6.448  -3.416 0.002899 **  x1:x3         -0.350      6.448  -0.054 0.957279     x2:x3        -23.142      7.335  -3.155 0.005215 ** 
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 2.709 on 19 degrees of freedom   (6
> observations deleted due to missingness) Multiple R-squared: 
> 0.9162,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8942  F-statistic: 41.55 on 5 and 19 DF,  p-value: 1.387e-09
```

However, when I did 4 extra experiments to ceck if the measured response matched with the response predictd by the model it did not in 3 of them... The data adjusted to the model contains replicates of each experiment. some Cexp CV's are above 20%

Looking at QQplot a nonnormality of residuals arise:

[image]

The missmatches between predicted Y and measured Y can be explained by this QQplot? Could we think about we have left behind some variable which is afecting our system and that is why the equation fails to predic Y when checking out experiments?

Thank you

Comment: what is your data and key hypotheses ?justify your  model ?